Why does Git LFS migrated repo take up more space than non LFS version?
I am in the process of migrating a huge old SVN repo to Git. The last part of the process is migrating the resulting Git repo to use Git LFS in order to store all binaries elsewhere but the git repo.
I noticed that the size of the LFS migrated repo (for only one file type migrated, as a test) is larger than the input repo. Why is this? Does regular Git pack the binaries/files better than git LFS?
Here are my numbers:

Before LFS migration:

Total: 313GB


After LFS migration (right after):

objects: 317.3GB
lfs: 296.1GB
Total: 613.4GB


After LFS migration + git reflog expire && git gc --prune=now

objects: 161.3GB
lfs: 298.7GB
Total: 460.1GB


After all of the above + git gc --prune=now --aggressive

objects: 79.5GB
lfs: 298.7GB
Total: 378.3GB



So TLDR; is the LFS migrated (+ cleaned) version of the repo is 65.3GB larger than the non-migrated version (378.3GB vs 313GB).
Of course I understand the benefit of the LFS repo, especially when pushed to remote as a single clone will be much smaller, but atm on disk, they should be comparable as both still contain everything.
BTW, the reason I performed git gc in two steps above, once without --aggressive and once with, is the fact that my 64GB RAM machine ran out of memory while running with that flag the first time... I since set a limit for the "per thread usage" which may have helped it succeed the other time around. Or did even the first gc run without the flag in the end help that too?
I used BFG repo cleaner for the LFS migration
